# jQuery.parseJSON trouble

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm pretty unfamiliar with JSON, as I haven't used it too much and I'm trying to learn some of it.

So I have an ajax request that gives me this: `[{"palvelu_id":"1","palvelu_nimi":"Meikkikoulutus","palvelu_kuvaus":"Kuvaus","palvelu_hinta":"10"}]`

And I'm trying to use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to use it on a page.

```
var palveluData = $.parseJSON(d);
$("#ajanvarausInfo").html(palveluData.palvelu_kuvaus+"<br>"+palveluData.palvelu_hinta);
```

But I get undefined as answer, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Post more of your code. It may already be automatically parsed.

Comment: @Blazemonger If I `console.log(d)` I get `[{"palvelu_id":"1","palvelu_nimi":"Meikkikoulutus","palvelu_kuvaus":"Kuvaus","palvelu_hinta":"10"}]`

Comment: Please post your Ajax code.

Comment: @Blazemonger Problem got solved already, it's just basic `$.ajax({})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the first element of the array:

```
$("#ajanvarausInfo").html(palveluData[0].palvelu_kuvaus+"<br>...");
```

If the array has more than 1 element you should iterate through the array, you can use jQuery `$.each()` utility function.

Comment: So I don't need to use `.parseJSON` at all?

Comment: @Christian It depends, if you are using jQuery for getting the JSON, you can set the `dataType` property to `json` then you don't need to parse the response.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using jQuery for the ajax call, and php returns a json string.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT::**

Wow, looks like ive kept the window open for to long before replying -.-

You have an outter array there, so you need to take that into account ( your php side might be not correct )

```
$("#ajanvarausInfo").html(palveluData[0].palvelu_kuvaus+"<br>"+palveluData[0].palvelu_hinta);
```

Usually you not need that when properly setting everything up

```
$.ajax ({
   url: 'myurl',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { key_value pairs here },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response){

      $("#ajanvarausInfo").html(response.palvelu_kuvaus+"<br>"+response.palvelu_hinta);

   });
});
```

On the php side

```
$response = array(
   "palvelu_id" => "1", 
   "palvelu_nimi" => "Meikkikoulutus", 
   "palvelu_kuvaus" => "Kuvaus", 
   "palvelu_hinta" => "10"
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: My php is just fine. Just a basic PDO query to MySQL and json_encode for `$smt->fetchAll()`.